# Issue with LDO in a PWM high current circuit for heating element

Tags: pwm, ldo

I’m building a circuit to control a heating element using a ESP32 as MCU.

The circuit is simple. A 2S lipo battery (8.4 V) as power source and 2 N-channel MOSFETs controlled by PWM in order to regulate the power sent to the element at 65 Hz. The current is sensed by a shunt resistor and a INA180 plus a comparator as Alarm system to avoid overcurrent. A N-channel MOSFET as reverse polarity protection.

All was working great, but when I tried to add short circuit protection the problem started.

The output of the comparator is connected to an interrupt pin of ESP32 and VRef is set by DAC of ESP32. That works great, I set the limit with DAC, and if current exceed the limit, comparator output goes high and ESP32 detect the interrupt and stop PWM.

But, when heating element is in short, the LDO gets damaged.

I made a similar circuit before and working well, but because the lack of components currently in the market, I must change several parts like MOSFETs, LDO and current sensors.

Please can you check my circuit and give me your considerations about what can be wrong in it?

[image]